# How can I manage a fork pool in Perl?

Tags: perl, logic, fork

I'm setting something up to SSH out to several servers in 'batches'. I basically want to maintain 5 connections at a time, and when one finishes open up another (following an array of server IPs).

I'm wondering for something like this should I be using [fork()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html)? If so, what logic can I use to ensure that the I maintain 5 children at a time?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453432/in-perl-how-can-i-wait-for-threads-to-end-in-parallel/2454146#2454146

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Forking (or threading) is what you want, but you should look at [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) for modules that will provide most of what you need to prevent you from reinventing the wheel and going through the learning pains of what you need to do.

For example, [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Parallel::ForkManager) looks like it's EXACTLY what you want.

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

$pm = new Parallel::ForkManager($MAX_PROCESSES);

foreach $data (@all_data) {
  # Forks and returns the pid for the child:
  my $pid = $pm->start and next; 

  ... do some work with $data in the child process ...

  $pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
}
```

Comment: but ForkManager doesn't really seem to support a pool but just a cap in the concurrent number of processes? start seems documented to always do a new fork for each iteration. Is there a library supporting real pooling of fork processes so they don't need to be forked for each iteration?

Comment: That may be correct.  What I generally use these days is Thread::Pool::Simple.  It automatically handles a min/max amount of threads you can define, and manages how many are active based on workload, and allows for pre/post actions for each job.  I've used it to good effect for quite a few years now.  It does require threads, which is unfortunate for those that use a Perl compiled without ithreads.  AnyEvent::Fork::Pool looks like a good choice if that is the case, but I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 5):

There are several modules that solve exactly this problem. See [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Parallel::ForkManager), [Forks::Super](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Forks::Super), or [Proc::Queue](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Proc::Queue), for example.

Comment: Proc::Queue rocks for existing scripts since the actual forking action doens't have to be changed. Great suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Net::OpenSSH::Parallel;

my $pssh = Net::OpenSSH::Parallel->new(connections => 5);

for my $ip (@ips) {
  $pssh->add_host($ip);
}

$pssh->push('*', command => 'do this');
$pssh->push('*', command => 'do that');
$pssh->push('*', scp_get => 'foo', 'bar-%HOST%');
$pssh->push('*', scp_put => 'doz', 'there');

$pssh->run;
```

Answer (score 0):

My personal forking(!) favourite is [`Proc::Fork`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Proc-Fork/)

General overview from pod:

```
use Proc::Fork;

run_fork {
    child {
        # child code goes here.
    }
    parent {
        my $child_pid = shift;
        # parent code goes here.
        waitpid $child_pid, 0;
    }
    retry {
        my $attempts = shift;
        # what to do if if fork() fails:
        # return true to try again, false to abort
        return if $attempts > 5;
        sleep 1, return 1;
    }
    error {
        # Error-handling code goes here
        # (fork() failed and the retry block returned false)
    }
};
```

And to limit the number of maximum processes running for something like SSH batches then this should do the trick:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use POSIX qw(:sys_wait_h);
use Proc::Fork;

my $max = 5;
my %pids;

my @ssh_files = (
    sub { system "scp file0001 baz@foo:/somedir/." },
    ...
    sub { system "scp file9999 baz@foo:/somedir/." },

);

while (my $proc = shift @ssh_files) {

    # max limit reached
    while ($max == keys %pids) {
        # loop thru pid list until a child is released
        for my $pid (keys %procs) {
            if (my $kid = waitpid($pid, WNOHANG)) {
                delete $pids{ $kid };
                last;
            }
        }
    }

    run_fork {
        parent {
            my $child = shift;
            $pids{ $child } = 1;
        }
        child {
            $proc->();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

/I3az/

Comment: Does Proc::Fork throttle the number of background processes? How does this answer the OP?

Comment: @mobrule: Sorry got called away! There's nothing specific (that I know off!) in Proc:Fork for throttling.  So revert to normal waitpid measures (see my updated example).