# Pipeline For Downloading and Processing Files In Unix/Linux Environment With Perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix, download, pipeline

I have a list of files URLS where I want to download them:

```
http://somedomain.com/foo1.gz
http://somedomain.com/foo2.gz
http://somedomain.com/foo3.gz
```

What I want to do is the following for each file:

1. Download foo1,2.. in parallel with `wget` and `nohup`.
2. Every time it completes download process them with `myscript.sh`

What I have is this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

@files = glob("foo*.gz");

foreach $file (@files) {
   my $downurls = "http://somedomain.com/".$file;
   system("nohup wget $file &");
   system("./myscript.sh $file >> output.txt");
}
```

The problem is that I can't tell the above pipeline when does the file finish downloading.
So now it myscript.sh doesn't get executed properly.

What's the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try combining the commands using `&&`, so that the 2nd one runs only after the 1st one completes successfully.

```
system("(nohup wget $file  && ./myscript.sh $file >> output.txt) &");
```

Answer (score 2):

Why to do this using perl. use bash instead. Below is just a sample.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in foo1 foo2 foo3
do
    wget http://samedomain.com/$file.gz .

    if [ -f $file.gz ];
    then
        ./myscript.sh $file.gz >> output.txt
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want parallel processing, you can do it yourself with forking, or use a built in module to handle it for you.  Try [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Parallel%3a%3aForkManager).  You can see a bit more on it's usage in [How can I manage a fork pool in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510306), but the CPAN page for the module will have the real useful info.  You probably want something like this:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $MAX_PROCESSES = 8; # 8 parallel processes max
my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager($MAX_PROCESSES);

my @files = glob("foo*.gz");

foreach $file (@all_data) {
  # Forks and returns the pid for the child:
  my $pid = $pm->start and next; 

  my $downurls = "http://somedomain.com/".$file;
  system("wget $file");
  system("./myscript.sh $file >> output.txt");

  $pm->finish; # Terminates the child process
}

print "All done!\n";
```

Comment: The inner loop is taken from the request's example, I suggest checking the return value of the system call to be sure that the commands executed correctly.  You have to right shift by 8 to get the shell exit code.  if ((system("command") >> 8) == 0) { ... }