# How to control multi-threads synchronization in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, thread-synchronization

I got array with [a-z,A-Z] ASCII numbers like so: `my @alphabet = (65..90,97..122);`

So main thread functionality is checking each character from alphabet and return string if condition is true.

Simple example :

```
    my @output = ();
    for my $ascii(@alphabet){
      thread->new(\sub{ return chr($ascii); });
    }
```

I want to run thread on every ASCII number, then put letter from thread function into array in the correct order.

So in out case array `@output` should be dynamic and contain `[a..z,A-Z]` after all threads finish their job.

How to check, is all threads is done and keep the order?

Comment: I take this as a toy example made up to accommodate a complete question about thread synchronization.  If not, what is described is much too little to spread across threads.  In Perl in particular, threads are heavy and you normally want a few of them each doing more work rather than many each doing little. The good advice you got in the last part of the [answer by Zac B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103050/4653379) applies even (much) more in Perl.

Comment: (I meant to say that threads are heavy in Perl, not in general...)

Comment: Truth! Well, they're heavi*er* in Perl than some other runtimes, but are heavy in general too :) Unless you're using green threads (e.g. Go, Stackless) or some other system that coordinates multiplexing work onto "real" OS threads without the programmer noticing, setup/teardown is still surprisingly expensive.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `$thread->join`, which waits for a thread to finish. It's documented [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html), and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453432/in-perl-how-can-i-wait-for-threads-to-end-in-parallel) may also help.

Since in your case it looks like the work being done in the threads is roughly equal in cost (no thread is going to take a long time more than any other), you can just `join` each thread in order, like so, to wait for them all to finish:

```
# Store all the threads for each letter in an array.
my @threads = map { thread->new(\sub{ return chr($_); }) } @alphabet;
my @results = map { $_->join } @threads;
```

Since, when the first thread returns from `join`, the others are likely already done and just waiting for "join" to grab their return code, or about to be done, this gets you pretty close to "as fast as possible" parallelism-wise, and, since the threads were created in order, `@results` is ordered already for free.

Now, if your threads *can* take variable amounts of time to finish, or if you need to do some time-consuming processing in the "main"/spawning thread before plugging child threads' results into the output data structure, `join`ing them in order might not be so good. In that case, you'll need to somehow either: a) detect thread "exit" events as they happen, or b) poll to see which threads have exited.

You can detect thread "exit" events using signals/notifications sent from the child threads to the main/spawning thread. The easiest/most common way to do that is to use the `cond_wait` and `cond_signal` functions from [`threads::shared`](https://metacpan.org/pod/threads::shared). Your main thread would wait for signals from child threads, process their output, and store it into the result array. If you take this approach, you should preallocate your result array to the right size, and provide the output index to your threads (e.g. use a C-style `for` loop when you create your threads and have them return `($result, $index_to_store)` or similar) so you can store results in the right place even if they are out of order.

You can poll which threads are done using the `is_joinable` thread instance method, or using the `threads->list(threads::joinable)` and `threads->list(threads::running)` methods in a loop (hopefully not a busy-waiting one; adding a sleep call--even a subsecond one from [`Time::HiRes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes)--will save a lot of performance/battery in this case) to detect when things are done and grab their results.

**Important Caveat**: spawning a huge number of threads to perform a lot of work in parallel, especially if that work is small/quick to complete, can cause performance problems, and it might be better to use a smaller number of threads that each do more than one "piece" of work (e.g. spawn a small number of threads, and each thread uses the `threads::shared` functions to lock and pop the first item off of a shared array of "work to do" and do it rather than map work to threads as 1:1). There are two main performance problems that arise from a 1:1 mapping:

1. the overhead (in memory and time) of spawning and joining each thread is much higher than you'd think ([benchmark](https://metacpan.org/pod/Benchmark) it on threads that don't do anything, just `return`, to see). If the work you need to do is fast, the overhead of thread management for tons of threads can make it much slower than just managing a few re-usable threads.
2. If you end up with a lot more threads than there are logical CPU cores and each thread is doing CPU-intensive work, or if each thread is accessing the same resource (e.g. reading from the same disks or the same rows in a database), you hit a performance cliff pretty quickly. Tuning the number of threads to the "resources" underneath (whether those are CPUs or hard drives or whatnot) tends to yield much better throughput than trusting the thread scheduler to switch between many more threads than there are available resources to run them on. The reasons this is slow are, very broadly:
3. Because the thread scheduler (part of the OS, not the language) can't know enough about what each thread is trying to do, so [preemptive scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)) cannot optimize for performance past a certain point, given that limited knowledge.
4. The OS usually tries to give most threads a reasonably fair shot, so it can't reliably say "let one run to completion and then run the next one" unless you explicitly bake that into the code (since the alternative would be unpredictably starving certain threads for opportunities to run). Basically, switching between "run a slice of thread 1 on resource X" and "run a slice of thread 2 on resource X" doesn't get you anything once you have more threads than resources, and adds some overhead as well.

TL;DR threads don't give you performance increases past a certain point, and after that point they can make performance *worse*. When you can, reuse a number of threads corresponding to available resources; don't create/destroy individual threads corresponding to tasks that need to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Zac B's answer, you can use the following if you want to reuse threads:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Thread::Pool::Simple qw( );

$| = 1;

my $pool = Thread::Pool::Simple->new(
   do => [ sub {
      select(undef, undef, undef, (200+int(rand(8))*100)/1000);
      return chr($_[0]);
   } ],
);

my @alphabet = ( 65..90, 97..122 );

print $pool->remove($_) for map { $pool->add($_) } @alphabet;
print "\n";
```

The results are returned in order, as soon as they become available.

Comment: Wow, so much work for which you need two simple lines in Erlang https://stackoverflow.com/a/20573151/49197

Comment: @Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil,  Same in Perl. See update. :) (Pity the worker sub can be defined when the job is added, though. That said, it's just a question of writing the interface.)

Comment: Well, it's better. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of Parallel::WorkUnit so I'm partial to it.  And I thought adding ordered responses was actually a great idea.  It does it with forks, not threads, because forks are more widely supported and they often perform better in Perl.

```
my $wu = Parallel::WorkUnit->new();
for my $ascii(@alphabet){
    $wu->async(sub{ return chr($ascii); });
}
@output = $wu->waitall();
```

If you want to limit the number of simultaneous processes:

```
my $wu = Parallel::WorkUnit->new(max_children => 5);
for my $ascii(@alphabet){
    $wu->queue(sub{ return chr($ascii); });
}
@output = $wu->waitall();
```